# What is the easiest way to implement self collusion of cloth material?

Tags: graphics, collision-detection, physics

I am trying to implement a cloth simulation system with self collusion. I implemented the whole cloth using particle system with spring forces. (i.e. I have a grid of vertices of the cloth) Now, I need a simple method to implement self collusion as well. Actually, both collusion detection and response. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bump. This sounds like a really hard problem, but I have wondered the same thing myself before.

Comment: @theJollySin Yes, it is unfortunately. I could not solve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how simple (and inexact) you want it:

Simplest variant:
- Choose a high resolution of cloth with regard to vertices. Use a sphere at each vertex, big/many enough to not leave wholes. Create springs for each contact (has to be redone each time step). The time step has to be small enough to avoid tunneling (although sphere-sphere continuous is easy to detect, but the resolution might be trickier if you don't want to backtrack the solution).

More exact variant: Trimesh-trimesh (or spline-spline) with continuous collision detection on the detection part. Some rigid body contact modeling with friction for the response part.

There are many articles on the topic. 
Barraff and Witkin 1998 http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs667/2005sp/readings/baraff98.pdf is a starter, but has several issues.

A simple literature search will provide many more.